# Add CSS only to administrator's wordpress dashboard

Tags: css, wordpress, dashboard

I am using WordPress.
Is there any way to add CSS on administrator's dashboard and not take effect on other users' dashboards?

I tried that but worked for all users

```
    function custom_css() {
  echo '<style>
    #my_element{display:none;}
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: The admin panel uses its own theme. Make changes to it via FTP, if nothing else.

Comment: Also: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I add a function in functions.php child theme but it takes effect in all users.

Comment: Post the code you tried in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your css rules / class in a specific css files (say "admin.css").
Then in your functions file use this code.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_styles_for_admin' );
function custom_styles_for_admin(){
   if( current_user_can('manage_options') ){
      wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin.css', false, '1.0.0' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.